# Javascript IF statement, detecting null not working

Tags: javascript

I have a null variable that is behaving weird. For some reason I can't seem to detect whether or not it is null! The var is called `emailFromUrl`.

```
   console.log(emailFromUrl); //returns null
   console.log(emailFormUrl.toString()); //returns null
   console.log(emailFromUrl === null); //false!
   console.log(emailFromUrl != null); //true!
   console.log(typeof emailFromUrl); //string
   console.log(!emailFromUrl); //false!
   console.log(emailFromUrl === ""); //false
```

What the heck is going on here?

**The answer:**

```
   console.log(emailFromUrl === 'null'); //true!
```

The unfiltered console log:

```
Test71 | emailFromUrl : null | emailFromUrl === null : false | emailFromUrl != null : true | emailFromUrl.toString() : null | typeof emailFromUrl : string | !emailFromUrl : false | emailFromUrl === "" : false | emailFromUrl === "null" : true
```

Comment: What happens if you run this `console.log(typeof emailFromUrl);` ?

Comment: You last log clearly shows it is `not equal to null`.

Comment: What kind of null are you talking about?  Do you mean you've defined it but it's undefined? `var emailFromUrl` or that it's defined as null `var emailFromUrl = ''`

Comment: As far as I can tell, console.log(...) _returns_ undefined. Your string is probably empty. Nothing prints out, it's not null, it is not null, and it has a type of string. Sounds like an empty string.

Comment: @FireLizzard. My thoughts exactly.

Comment: The var was previously defined. I am just not understanding its behavior in this part of the script.

Comment: The last line is impossible if all the rest are true!

Comment: Actually I just solved this. Please remove the down vote. This is all true.

Comment: When you say console.log returns null, do you mean prints out or actually returns null? Because what it returns is irrelevant as far as I know.

Comment: hold on, if `console.log(emailFromUrl);` returns null, `console.log(emailFormUrl.toString());` should return an error

Comment: @PitaJ. Something here smell... I wrote it in my answer.

Comment: @FireLizzard all I can see is what is printed in the console, so I was considering 'printed' and 'returned' as the same thing.

Comment: @PitaJ. I got the feeling, if all the lines are right, he's getting `"null"` instead of `null`.

Comment: @gdoron That's the only thing that makes any sense

Comment: @gdoron Yeh, I just checked it and that must be what it is

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping with this. What a weird senerio, thought I was loosing my mind!

Comment: `null.toString` should error, not return `null`

Comment: @zzzzBov This is true. But `"null".toString()` will return `"null"` which is indistinguishable from `null` in the console.

Comment: @Fresheyeball, chrome console prints `null` in a lighter grey and `'null'` as a black value. If you don't have issues with colorblindness it's a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps `emailFromurl` value is just a literal `null` string? ) That will explain all the results you get in your question, I think.

Comment: It's easy actually: if `emailFromUrl` is truthy value (and it is, as its negation is false) and it's a string, there's only one value which will give `'null'` when stringified - yep, `'null'` itself. )

Answer (score 1):

well the === operator checks the value and type. emailFromUrl is of type string not null which it why it evaluates to false there.

Comment: Oh also, do a check to see if it is undefined, i.e. emailFromUrl == undefined

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want specific logic based on it being null, you can check if the object is "falsy" (if the object is undefined, 0 or null)

```
if(!emailFromUrl) {
    // handle the null scenario
}
```